# Boolean indexing assignment of a numpy array to a numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, boolean

I am seeing some behavior with Boolean indexing that I do not understand, and I was hoping to find some clarification here.

First off, this is the behavior I am seeking...

```
>>>
>>> a = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.ndarray)
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
>>> b = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> b
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> a[5] = b
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), 0,
       0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
>>>
```

The reason for choosing an ndarray of ndarrays is because I will be appending the arrays stored in the super array, and they will all be of different lengths.  I chose the type ndarray instead of list for the super array so I can have access to all of numpys clever indexing features.

anyway if i make a Boolean indexer and use that to assign, say, b+5 at position 1, it does something I didn't expect

```
>>> indexer = np.zeros(10,dtype='bool')
>>> indexer
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> indexer[1] = True
>>> indexer
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a[indexer] = b+5
>>> a
array([0, 5, 0, 0, 0, array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), 0,
       0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
>>>
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?  I would like the result to be

```
>>> a[1] = b+5
>>> a
array([0, array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]), 0, 0,
       0, array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
>>>
```

The final goal is to have a lot of "b" arrays stored in B, and to assign them to a like this

```
>>> a[indexer] = B[indexer]
```

EDIT:

found possible work around based on the discussion below. I can wrap my data in a class if i need to

```
>>>
>>> class myclass:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.data = np.random.rand(1)
...
>>>
>>> b = myclass()
>>> b
<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002871A4AD198> 
>>> b.data
array([ 0.40185378])
>>>
>>> a[indexer] = b
>>> a
array([None, <__main__.myclass object at 0x000002871A4AD198>, None, None,
       None, None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
>>> a[1].data
array([ 0.40185378])
```

EDIT:
this actually fails.  I cannot allocate anything to the data field when indexed

Comment: it does not :( it fails... but thanks for the info!  i will do that in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
In [203]: a = np.empty(5, object)
In [204]: a
Out[204]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [205]: a[3]=np.arange(3)
In [206]: a
Out[206]: array([None, None, None, array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
```

So simple indexing works with this object array.

Boolean indexing works for reading:

```
In [207]: a[np.array([0,0,0,1,0], dtype=bool)]
Out[207]: array([array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
In [208]: a[np.array([0,0,1,0,0], dtype=bool)]
```

But has problems when writing:

```
Out[208]: array([None], dtype=object)
In [209]: a[np.array([0,0,1,0,0], dtype=bool)]=np.arange(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-209-c1ef5580972c> in <module>()
----> 1 a[np.array([0,0,1,0,0], dtype=bool)]=np.arange(2)

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 2 
input values to the 1 output values where the mask is true
```

`np.where(<boolean>)` and `[2]` also give problems:

```
In [221]: a[[2]]=np.arange(3)
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: assignment will raise an 
error in the future, most likely because your index result shape does 
not match the value array shape. You can use `arr.flat[index] = values`    
to keep the old behaviour.
```

So whatever reason, indexed assignment to an object dtype array does not work as well as with regular ones.

Even the recommended `flat` doesn't work

```
In [226]: a.flat[[2]]=np.arange(3)
In [227]: a
Out[227]: array([None, None, 0, array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
```

I can assign a non-list/array object

```
In [228]: a[[2]]=None
In [229]: a
Out[229]: array([None, None, None, array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
In [230]: a[[2]]={3:4}
In [231]: a
Out[231]: array([None, None, {3: 4}, array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
In [232]: idx=np.array([0,0,1,0,0],bool)
In [233]: a[idx]=set([1,2,3])
In [234]: a
Out[234]: array([None, None, {1, 2, 3}, array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
```

`object` dtype arrays are at the edge of `numpy` array functionality.

---

Look at what we get with `getitem`.  With a scalar index we get what object is stored in that slot (in my latest case, a `set`).  But with `[[2]]` or boolean, we get another object array.

```
In [235]: a[2]
Out[235]: {1, 2, 3}
In [236]: a[[2]]
Out[236]: array([{1, 2, 3}], dtype=object)
In [237]: a[idx]
Out[237]: array([{1, 2, 3}], dtype=object)
In [238]: a[idx].shape
Out[238]: (1,)
```

I suspect that when `a[idx]` is on the LHS, it tries to convert the RHS to an object array first:

```
Out[241]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=object)
In [242]: _.shape
Out[242]: (3,)
In [243]: np.array(set([1,2,3]), object)
Out[243]: array({1, 2, 3}, dtype=object)
In [244]: _.shape
Out[244]: ()
```

In the case of a `set` the resulting array has a single element and can be put in the (1,) slot.  But when the RHS is a list or array the result is a n element array, e.g. (3,), which does not fit in the (1,) slot.

### Solution (sort of)

If you want to assign a list/array to a slot in a object array with some form of advanced indexing (boolean or list), first put that item in an object array of the correct size:

```
In [255]: b=np.empty(1,object)
In [256]: b[0]=np.arange(3)
In [257]: b
Out[257]: array([array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
In [258]: b.shape
Out[258]: (1,)
In [259]: a[idx]=b
In [260]: a
Out[260]: array([None, None, array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), None], dtype=object)
```

---

Or working with your slightly large arrays:

```
In [264]: a = np.zeros(10, dtype=object)
In [265]: b = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
In [266]: a[5] = b
In [267]: c = np.zeros(1, dtype=object)  # intermediate object wrapper
In [268]: c[0] = b+5
In [269]: idx = np.zeros(10,bool)
In [270]: idx[1]=True
In [271]: a[idx] = c
In [272]: a
Out[272]: 
array([0, array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]), 0, 0,
       0, array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]), 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)
```

If `idx` has n True items, the `c` has to have shape that will broadcast to (n,)

Comment: It looks less buggy when I make sure that the RHS dtype matches the LHS (i.e. object dtype).  Then it's just the standard business of broadcastable shapes.  It comes back to that old question - how to unambiguously turn a list or array into an object array of known shape.

Comment: is it possible to assign and append with this indexing as well?  if we had the right shape of C with values in it, does a[idx].append(C[idx]) make any... sense?

Comment: `a[idx]` is an object array, not a list.  It does not have an append method.  `a[2]` could be a list, and thus be appendable.  You could put a large list or array in `c`, and then assign that.